# which storage should I use for saving and retrieving the audio recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, storage, audio-recording

I am working on a reminder app and I want to save and show that recording on a calendar.I am totally new to iOS .I have done the recording part(AVAudio Recorder) but not able to decide what should I use for showing that on a calendar :( Suggestions plz??

Comment: you can add any icon on a date & play your stored audio on date selection.  look at the examples https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=calendar

Comment: @Gagan_iOS thanks mate but that code is in Swift :(